# unicode characters displayed as question marks in intellij idea 2022

Tags: intellij-idea, unicode, character-encoding

i am using windows7. when i run the kotlin file in intellij ide 2022 (JDK18), the unicode characters are displayed as ? marks only. i tried help / edit vm options in ide and added -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 and also -Dconsole.encoding=UTF-8. nothing worked out. any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Either the file is being opened with the wrong encoding or the font does not have glyphs for the characters.  It would help to see some bytes from the file and the expected values for these bytes (remember that a single character may require multiple bytes to encode).

Comment: the sample code for test is given here. fun main() { val name = "சரவணன்" println(name) }.  the unicode characters are shown correctly in the intellij IDE editor as well as here too. but when i run the main.kts file, the result is shown in ? marks instead of unicode characters.  this is the problem.

Comment: Do you see regular `?` (U+003F,  *Question Mark*) or rather [Glyph 0: the `.notdef` glyph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/recom#glyph-0-the-notdef-glyph) which mostly _looks_ like `�` *Replacement Character*? Please [edit] your question to elaborate your [mcve].

Comment: yes, it is not a regular question mark but a replacement character for unicode. you can see my sample code given above.

Comment: try to add the -Dsun.stdout.encoding=UTF-8 there (and probably restart the IDE)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a known issue: *[IDEA-291006](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-291006/Running-the-Java-project-by-using-the-JDK-18-prints-the-garbled-characters-in-console-when-try-printing-the-non-ASCII-characters) Running the Java project by using the JDK 18 prints the garbled characters in console when try printing the non-ASCII characters in the code*. As a workaound:

- Click Run | `Edit configurations`, add the `-Dfile.encoding=<your_system_default_encoding>` (example: `-Dfile.encoding=gbk` in Chinese encoding) in this application's VM options.
- Use JDK 17 or the old version.

Comment: edited configurations and added -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 in VM options. no gain. have to try with JDK 17 or older.

Comment: atlast, the problem is solved by using windows 10 os. thank you for all.